# How to use PageSetup in vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I tried to implement `PageSetup` class

```
With objWb.Worksheets("test")
.PageSetup.RightMargin=0.5              'executes okay
.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal     'throws an error
.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape    'throws an error
End With
```

ERROR: `Unable to set the PaperSize property of the PageSetup class` 
although `.PageSetup.RightMargin=0.5` executed fine. Why don't the next two lines execute?

How to se `paperLegal` and `landscape` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are Excel constants. You'll need to define them yourself. Use the Object Browser within Excel's VBA screen (hit ALT+F11 to get to VBA, then hit F2 to bring up the Object Browser).

```
Const xlPaperLegal = 5
Const xlLandscape  = 2
```